# how to fix ERROR 1044, ERROR 1046 and being unable to change password to users?

Tags: mysql, authentication, mariadb-10.3

I'm already too tired of trying so many different things and I can't even bypass an error which is running. I know some of you might think it's a duplicate question, but I've seen dozens of questions, so I don't think the answer is so simple, nor is duplicated.

---

This are some of the many solutions I unsuccessfully tried:

[update command is denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980032/update-command-is-denied-for-user)

[Can't change user password on MySQL using UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218479/cant-change-user-password-on-mysql-using-update)

[Error: select command denied to user '<userid>'@'<ip-address>' for table '<table-name>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)

[MySQL Error: #1142 - SELECT command denied to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956195/mysql-error-1142-select-command-denied-to-user/32091813)

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/

[ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,588296

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

---

`# mysql -u root -p`

when it asks for password, no matter what I type it shows

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 430
Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

---

`show databases;` only shows

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

when I type

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

Notice it says `%` instead of localhost, is that a hint of something going on? have you encountered the same problem and were able to solve that?

---

even if I type the right password. I have another user but I can't change its password.

---

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, plugin from user;
```

shows

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

---

I feel like I really tried everything, I mean I've been like this for so many hours now, and I've changed mysql passwords many times in the past, using console in windows and linux, I have no idea what's going on!

---

***EIDT:*** as suggested in comments here is the output for `SELECT user, host, plugin from mysql.user;`

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host, plugin from mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

---

here's the output to `> SHOW GRANTS;`

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket USING '*227A46552108541F24FF4915F91'              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

---

Comment: Try `SELECT user, host, plugin from mysql.user`.

Comment: Hi, @aynber I thought I posted about accessing that table. Edited the question, I can't access mysql.user either,

Comment: It sounds like something is messed up with your permissions, since root appears to only have usage instead of all privileges. This is a bit beyond me, but  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges might be of some help

Comment: if you have a backup use it to restore your system.